# Is it possible to build a bot on mac with LUIS, Microsoft Bot Framework and external APIs?

Tags: visual-studio, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Is it possible to build a bot on mac with LUIS, Microsoft Bot Framework and external APIs? I am using a 128gb mac and cannot afford to install dualboot for Windows and Visual Studio.

I still want to build a bot (by coding, not with web GUI) using Microsoft Bot Framework, LUIS and some external APIs. I saw many people using Visual Studio to code a bot with BotFramework and LUIS...but wanna know if it is possible without Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Bot Framework you can build bots  both in C# and in Node.js. Nowadays Mac is a first citizen for Microsoft and there are developers tools that will run smoothly in MacOS.

Both [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) runs on a Mac. The new [Bot Framework emulator](http://Bot%20Framework%20Emulator%20_%20Documentation%20_%20Bot%20Framework.html) also runs on Mac.

If you prefer to code in C#, you can also use Mono.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use Nodejs to build bot using Microsoft Bot Framework in Mac. For IDE you can use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which is a cross-platform offering from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build Bots on Mac.

Not only does the BotFramework have a NodeJS SDK but you can also build C# Bots on VS for Mac.

There are specific templates for building Bots using VS2017. You just need to modify the templates to work for VS for mac.

I've already gone ahead and provided the modified templates and how to get started here: https://github.com/User1m/botframework-template-vs-for-mac

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, not at this time @JSWilson. But thanks for the interest in it!